# What Windows Forms control would be used to create a dockable window like Visual Studio Solution Explorer?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

I want to be able to use things like the Solution Explorer window or the Properties window from Visual Studio in my Windows Forms application. I am not sure what the term for it is so I cannot look it up.

Comment: That will be a Dock Manager / Dock Panel. https://sourceforge.net/projects/dockpanelsuite/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a normal panel? You might want to code all the contents of the solution explorer and the properties panel. The panel can be docked from its properties. Then, for example, if autosize is disabled, you write

`If ...... Then
_something_.Autosize = false
End If`

But that's a **TON** of code!
I don't think you can reproduce the solution explorer dynamically nor the properties panel. Besides, do you need to change *all* properties of an object at once? It looks like you are trying to remake visual basic dynamically. Well, that can't happen. Not with the current versions of vb.net, at least.

Answer (score 0):

You should try involving things with panel that appears on your screen with all the settings in it, but like TGamer, there is a lot of code to do. But start with showing and hiding the panel to start with. Maybe try importing the settings through a VS file stored somewhere in your directory.